# Searching within concatenated id's using regex

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to split up and identify some IDs, which are poorly constructed manually.

Input (left) and expected output (right):

1. **'145.100, 150.200'**  =>  '145.100', '150.20'
2. **'160.10A'** =>  '160.10A'
3. **'145.100, 150.200'**  =>  '145.100', '150.200'
4. **'10.545'** => '10.545'
5. **'132.134, .9999, .456'** => '132.134, '132.9999', '132.456'
6. **'121.111, .6577, .88A, 112.4444'** => '121.111', '121.6577', '121.88A', '112.4444'

#6 is for me the tricky one, and i can't figure out how to solve it. The rest i have solved by dividing the concatenated ID in 1st half (before dot) and 2nd half and then putting them together after.

Small example within postgres is the following:

```
WITH 
    tmp AS 
        (
            SELECT '145.100, 150.200' AS dgunr
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '160.10A'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ' 10 .  545'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '132.134, .6577, .456'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444'
        ),
    h_dgu_re AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                dgunr,
                ',' || REPLACE(regexp_replace(upper(dgunr), '\s', '', 'g'), '.', '_') || ',' AS dgunr_re
            FROM tmp
        ),
    h_dgu_devide AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                dgunr,
                dgunr_re,
                (REGEXP_MATCHES(dgunr_re, '(,)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g')) AS dguall,
                (REGEXP_MATCHES(dgunr_re, '(,)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g'))[2] AS dgu1,
                (REGEXP_MATCHES(dgunr_re, '(_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g'))[2] AS dgu2,
                (REGEXP_MATCHES(dgunr_re, '(,_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g'))[2] AS dgu3
            FROM h_dgu_re
        )
    SELECT
        dgunr,
        dgunr_re,
        dguall[2] || '.' || dguall[4],
        dgu1,
        dgu3
    FROM h_dgu_devide
;
```

The sql output:

| dgunr | dgunr_re | dgu_concat | dgu1 | dgu2 | dgu3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 160.10A | ,160_10A, | 160.10A | 160 | 10A |  |
| 10 . 545 | ,10_545, | 10.545 | 10 | 545 |  |
| 132.134, .6577, .456 | ,132_134,_6577,_456, | 132.134 | 132 | 134 | 6577 |
| 132.134, .6577, .456 | ,132_134,_6577,_456, |  |  | 6577 | 456 |
| 132.134, .6577, .456 | ,132_134,_6577,_456, 456 |  |  |  |  |
| 121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444 | ,121_111,_6577,_88C,_999,112_4444, | 121.111 | 121 | 111 | 6577 |
| 121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444 | ,121_111,_6577,_88C,_999,112_4444, | 112.4444 | 112 | 6577 | 88C |
| 121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444 | ,121_111,_6577,_88C,_999,112_4444, |  |  | 88C | 999 |
| 121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444 | ,121_111,_6577,_88C,_999,112_4444, |  |  | 999 |  |
| 121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444 | ,121_111,_6577,_88C,_999,112_4444, |  |  | 4444 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me if you want the results as separate columns or an array.  Here is how I would approach getting the results into separate columns.  First, the regex approach seems overly complicated.  I would remove all spaces and use string_to_array to separate each element into an array.  Then, just check to see if the element starts with '.' or not and concatenate as needed:

```
WITH 
    tmp AS 
        (
            SELECT '145.100, 150.200' AS dgunr
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '160.10A'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ' 10 .  545'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '132.134, .6577, .456'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444'
        ),
     id_array AS (
            SELECT dgunr, 
            string_to_array(replace(dgunr, ' ', ''), ',') as id_array
            FROM tmp
     )
SELECT dgunr,
       id_array[1] as dg1,
       CASE WHEN starts_with(id_array[2], '.') THEN split_part(id_array[1], '.', 1) || id_array[2] ELSE id_array[2] END as dgu2,
       CASE WHEN starts_with(id_array[3], '.') THEN split_part(id_array[1], '.', 1) || id_array[3] ELSE id_array[3] END as dgu2,
       CASE WHEN starts_with(id_array[4], '.') THEN split_part(id_array[1], '.', 1) || id_array[4] ELSE id_array[4] END as dgu3,
       CASE WHEN starts_with(id_array[5], '.') THEN split_part(id_array[1], '.', 1) || id_array[5] ELSE id_array[5] END as dgu4

FROM id_array;

                dgunr                 |   dg1   |   dgu2   |  dgu2   |  dgu3   |   dgu4
--------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------
 145.100, 150.200                     | 145.100 | 150.200  |         |         |
 160.10A                              | 160.10A |          |         |         |
  10 .  545                           | 10.545  |          |         |         |
 132.134, .6577, .456                 | 132.134 | 132.6577 | 132.456 |         |
 121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444 | 121.111 | 121.6577 | 121.88c | 121.999 | 112.4444
(5 rows)
```

Comment: string_to_array is a much better solution than my own. Thanks :) My objective was initially to have several rows with the concatenated ID and a row for each of the divided ID, but that is an easy fix from here.

Comment: I found a new curve ball from the concatenated ID '10.12B, .7b, .8b, 11.6B, .8E, .9B, 144.4F' that i don't think will be handled by your method since e.g. '.8e' in yours would be '10.8E' and not 11.8e. But since i answered the initial problem i have accepted your answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So far this (not so elegant solution) fixed my problem

```
WITH 
tmp AS 
    (
        SELECT '145.100, 150.200' AS dgunr
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '160.10A'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ' 10 .  545'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '132.   134, .3456, .456'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '121.111, .6577, .88c, .999, 112.4444'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '10.12B, .7b, .8b, 11.6B, .8E, .9B, 144.4F'
    ),
tmp2 AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS object_num, 
            upper(dgunr) AS dgunr
        FROM tmp
    ),
tmp3 AS 
    (
        SELECT
            object_num,
            dgunr, 
            REGEXP_MATCHES(dgunr, '([0-9]*)(\s*\.\s*)([A-Z0-9]+)', 'g') AS dguall
        FROM tmp2
    ),
tmp4 AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            dgunr, 
            object_num, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY object_num) AS version_num, 
            NULLIF(dguall[1], '') AS dgu1, 
            dguall[3] AS dgu2
        FROM tmp3
    ),
tmp5 AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            dgunr, object_num, version_num, 
            COALESCE(
                dgu1,
                LAG(dgu1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 6) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 7) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 8) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 9) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 10) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 11) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 12) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 13) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 14) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 15) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 16) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 17) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 18) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num),
                LAG(dgu1, 19) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num), 
                LAG(dgu1, 20) OVER (PARTITION BY object_num ORDER BY version_num)
                ) AS dgu1, 
            dgu2
        FROM tmp4
        ORDER BY object_num, version_num
    )
SELECT 
    dgunr, dgu1 || '.' || dgu2 AS dgunr_edit
FROM tmp5
;
```